# Is there a setting to disable 'collapsing to definition' of comments in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio, comments, settings

Is there an outlining setting to disable 'collapsing to definition' of comments in Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comments - No.

But you can turn outlining off Edit-->Outlining-->Stop Outlining (Or CTRL+M, CTRL+P)